# Получение случайного значения из массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

Как можно получить каждый раз случайное значение из массива?

```js
let computer = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Перемешать массив каким-либо алгоритмом (какие либо способы предлагаются тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/6104996)
2. Затем брать постоянно первый или последний элемент (shift или pop)

Comment: Да сразу можно вырезать случайные элементы `arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length),1)[0]`